# Check U.K Postcode for Validation

Tags: c#

I need to check the U.K postcode against a list.

The U.K postcode is of a standard format but the list only contains the outward section that I need to check against.

The list contains a series of outward postcode with also some data relating to this outward postcode, so for example

```
AL     St Albans
B      Birmingham
BT     Belfast
TR     Taunton
TR21    Taunton X
TR22    Taunton Y
```

My aim is that when I get a postcode, for example B20 7TP, I can search and find Birmingham.

Any ideas??

The question is different to the ones referred to as possible answers, but in my case I need to check a full postcode against just the outward postcode.

Comment: So if you get the postcode `TR21 1AB` do you want to match `Taunton` or `Taunton X`? Similarly, how should the postcode `BT1 1AB` know to match `Belfast` and not `Birmingham`?

Comment: If postcode TR21 1AB is given then it needs to match Taunton X, similary BT1 1AB needs to match Belfast. Thanks.

Comment: TR is not Taunton but Truro,,,

Comment: @wakthar *I* know that. The challenge is properly defining that logic as your requirement.

Comment: @wakthar You can use the match groups from a regex found in the dupe question link

Answer (score 1):

**If you have the whole postcode and only want to use the outcode, remove the last three characters and use what remains.** All postcodes end with the pattern digit-alpha-alpha, so removing those characters will give the outcode; any string that does not fit that pattern or that does not give a valid outcode after removing that substring is not a valid postcode. ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Validation))

---

If you're willing to take on an external (and Internet-based) dependency, you could look at using something like https://postcodes.io, in particular the outcodes section of that API. I have no affiliation with postcodes.io; I just found it after a Google.

Per the documentation, /outcodes will return

- the outcode
- the eastings
- the northings
- the andministrative counties under the code
- the district/unitary authories under the code
- the administrative/electoral areas under the code
- the WGS84 logitude
- the WGS84 latitude
- the countries included in the code
- the parish/communities in the code

For reference, a call to /outcodes/TA1 returns:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "result": {
    "outcode": "TA1",
    "longitude": -3.10297767924529,
    "latitude": 51.0133987332761,
    "northings": 124359,
    "eastings": 322721,
    "admin_district": [
      "Taunton Deane"
    ],
    "parish": [
      "Taunton Deane, unparished area",
      "Bishop's Hull",
      "West Monkton",
      "Trull",
      "Comeytrowe"
   ],
    "admin_county": [
      "Somerset"
    ],
    "admin_ward": [
      "Taunton Halcon",
      "Bishop's Hull",
      "Taunton Lyngford",
      "Taunton Eastgate",
      "West Monkton",
      "Taunton Manor and Wilton",
      "Taunton Fairwater",
      "Taunton Killams and Mountfield",
      "Trull",
      "Comeytrowe",
      "Taunton Blackbrook and Holway"
    ],
    "country": [
      "England"
    ]
  }
}
```

If you have the whole postcode, the `/postcodes` endpoint will return considerably more detailed information which I will not include here, but it does include the outcode and the incode as separate fields.

I would, of course, recommend caching the results of any call to a remote API.

Comment: Without a doubt the right thing to do - not an answer to the question though.

Comment: @Jamiec I've added more detail; can you see anything I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

Build a regular expression from the list of known codes. Pay attention that the order of known codes in the regular expression matters. You need to use longer codes before shorter codes.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxLog.Clear();

    var regionList = BuildList();
    var regex = BuildRegex(regionList.Keys);

    TryMatch("B20 7TP", regionList, regex);
    TryMatch("BT1 1AB", regionList, regex);
    TryMatch("TR21 1AB", regionList, regex);
    TryMatch("TR0 00", regionList, regex);
    TryMatch("XX123", regionList, regex);
}

private static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> BuildList()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    result.Add("AL", "St Albans");
    result.Add("B", "Birmingham");
    result.Add("BT", "Belfast");
    result.Add("TR", "Taunton");
    result.Add("TR21", "Taunton X");
    result.Add("TR22", "Taunton Y");

    return result;
}

private static Regex BuildRegex(IEnumerable<string> codes)
{
    // Sort the code by length descending so that for example TR21 is sorted before TR and is found by regex engine
    // before the shorter match
    codes = from code in codes
            orderby code.Length descending
            select code;

    // Escape the codes to be used in the regex
    codes = from code in codes
            select Regex.Escape(code);

    // create Regex Alternatives
    string codesAlternatives = string.Join("|", codes.ToArray());

    // A regex that starts with any of the codes and then has any data following
    string lRegExSource = "^(" + codesAlternatives + ").*";

    return new Regex(lRegExSource, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
}


/// <summary>
/// Try to match the postcode to a region
/// </summary>
private bool CheckPostCode(string postCode, out string identifiedRegion, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> regionList, Regex regex)
{
    // Check whether we have any match at all
    Match match = regex.Match(postCode);
    bool result = match.Success;

    if (result)
    {
        // Take region code from first match group
        // and use it in dictionary to get region name
        string regionCode = match.Groups[1].Value;
        identifiedRegion = regionList[regionCode];
    }
    else
    {
        identifiedRegion = "";
    }

    return result;
}

private void TryMatch(string code, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> regionList, Regex regex)
{
    string region;

    if (CheckPostCode(code, out region, regionList, regex))
    {
        AppendLog(code + ": " + region);
    }
    else
    {
        AppendLog(code + ": NO MATCH");
    }
}

private void AppendLog(string log)
{
    textBoxLog.AppendText(log + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Produces this output:

> ```
> B20 7TP: Birmingham
> BT1 1AB: Belfast
> TR21 1AB: Taunton X
> TR0 00: Taunton
> XX123: NO MATCH
> ```

For your information, the regex built here is `^(TR21|TR22|AL|BT|TR|B).*`